# Why am I not recieving a response from the webrequest?

Tags: c#, .net, http-post, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

So i'm trying to learn how WebRequest & WebResponse works.
So far it seems a bit like when you create a TcpClient and listener and make them connect and then send a buffer inbetween them.

However this seems to be a bit different.
So what im doing here is that im making a request to a website, in this case Spotify (Thought I would try to login to spotify as my first project).

Using the POST method to post data to the website.

converting my string to a byteArray

changing the contenttype (Not really sure if im doing it right here, not 100% sure what the values can be)

and the length of the content is the length of the byteArray

I create a stream of data in which I will get the stream from the request.

and then I proceed to write the byteArray starting from the offset of 0 and then the length of the thing that im going to write.

then I close the dataStream.

Now I create a WebResponse (which will get the response to tell me if everything is okay or not (im assuming))

Then I print out the the statusdescription (It doesnt print out anything here not sure why)

Then I create a stream that contains the content from the server

and then I create a streamreader which will read the content..

The rest is pretty straight forward.

**Issue**
So the issue is that its not printing out anything to the console and I am not sure why. How do I make it print out?

**ERROR**

So I caught the exception and this is what img etting

> "The remote server returned an error: <405> Method not allowed."

**CODE**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Login Test";
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        tester();
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static void tester()
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post.   
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.spotify.com/en-SK/login");
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.  
            request.Method = "POST";
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.  
            string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.  
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.  
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.  
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.  
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.  
            dataStream.Close();
            // Get the response.  
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // Display the status.  
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.  
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.  
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.  
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            // Clean up the streams.  
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use Fiddler to watch the Http traffic flowing from your PC to the site, does it show that the site actually returns any response to your PC ? This will quickly tell you whether you should be expecting .net to receive anything.

Comment: I have no idea how to use Fiddler tbh.

Comment: It will massively ease any web based programming you are doing, and its free and simple to use. You can download it from here http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Yeah I have it on the PC, but I have no idea how to use it, I'm trying to refresh the website that im doing a request to but it doesnt seem to do anything.

Comment: I'm quite sure you are getting an exception but you are swallowing it. Try actually putting some handler code in the `catch`.

Comment: OK, so now it is more a question of how to use the Spotify API than how to use WebRequest. That means the URI you are using does not accept POST requests. It may be a GET, however I doubt it would take your login in the query string. So I think you need to research their API better.

Comment: But when using their API dont I need to do things with tokens etc? Like authenticate alot of stuff etc?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with their API, but yeah, it looks like [there is a significant process to go through.](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/) . There are examples, you will have to correctly translate them to C#. Maybe you want to consider [using someone else's work](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET) to make it easier.

Comment: Currently looking through it and boy.. Seems like such a struggle jsut to see if I can login to my account I dont even want to play song I just want to automate my login for me :P